# Postfix DSN success report

Tags: notifications, report, postfix-mta

I have Postfix.

When I'm trying to send email to unexisting address Postfix generate notification about bounce.

I found [Postfix DSN Support](http://www.postfix.org/DSN_README.html): it says "What notifications are sent: success, failure, delay, or none. Normally, Postfix informs the sender only when mail delivery is delayed or when delivery fails."

How can I enable success notifications?

**Updated**

I found solution ([here](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/dsn.html))

> Delivery Status Notification: How does it work?
>
> sendmail 8.7 has no hook to request a DSN from the commandline, it can
>   be only done in an ESMTP dialogue. This is quite reasonable, since
>   options (as introduced in sendmail 8.8), are barely flexible enough to
>   allow for something like this (slightly modified from the RFC):

The key is

> RCPT TO: NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY
>   ORCPT=rfc822;Bob@Big-Bucks.COM

Here is example of SMTP session via telnet:

```
R: 220 Pure-Heart.ORG SMTP server here
S: EHLO Pure-Heart.ORG
R: 250-Pure-Heart.ORG
R: 250-DSN
R: 250 SIZE
S: MAIL FROM:<Alice@Pure-Heart.ORG> RET=HDRS ENVID=QQ314159
R: 250 <Alice@Pure-Heart.ORG> sender ok
S: RCPT TO:<Bob@Big-Bucks.COM> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY ORCPT=rfc822;Bob@Big-Bucks.COM
R: 250 <Bob@Big-Bucks.COM> recipient ok
S: RCPT TO:<Carol@Ivory.EDU> NOTIFY=FAILURE ORCPT=rfc822;Carol@Ivory.EDU
R: 250 <Carol@Ivory.EDU> recipient ok
S: RCPT TO:<Dana@Ivory.EDU> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE ORCPT=rfc822;Dana@Ivory.EDU
R: 250 <Eric@Bombs.AF.MIL> recipient ok
S: RCPT TO:<Fred@Bombs.AF.MIL> NOTIFY=NEVER
R: 250 <Fred@Bombs.AF.MIL> recipient ok
```